# Loop doesn't stop when flag is set?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a program in which I need to stop a loop when a flag is true. This is a short example of that I want:

```
var aux = true;
for(i=0; i < limit && aux; i++)
{
   ...
   if (condition)
      aux = false;
}
```

When the condition should end the loop. But this is not true. What is the problem?

EDIT:

The code is as follows:

```
aux = true; 
for(j=posX+1; j <= limitXTop && aux; j++)
  if(j != limiteXSuperior)
  {
     if(map.getXY(j,posY)[0] == 2)
     {
        aux = false;
     }
     else
        // Change
     ...
  }
  ...
```

I print a message to check if the execution enter in the IF and it enter.

Comment: Why can't you use `break;` to exit the loop?

Comment: What is the `condition`? How it's being calculated?

Comment: In my simple test this seems to work. There must be something wrong with the `condition`. However you should use `break` statement.

Comment: The code you've shown us gives us **nothing**. We don't know what these variables are, how they change and what you are trying to achieve. On the other hand we've already answered your question.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the condition on the `for`, use only a `break` statement.

```
for(i=0; i < limit; i++)
{
   ...
   if (condition)
      break;
}
```

Comment: So obviously your `condition` is never true!

Comment: @user1306586 try to `alert()` inside your condition to see if its reached. With `break`, as I suggest, it will exit to loop.

Comment: I print a message to check if the execution enter in the IF and it enter. The loop is inside another loop. I use break but nothing happends.

Comment: If the loop is inside another loop, it is quiting once but is cautch on the parent loop. You will have to put this condition with break on the 2 loops if you want to exit from the 2.

Comment: I only want to exit in the inside loop.

Answer (score -1):

Let me guess ... `i` was not defined ?

Comment: It's true that it not defined but I tried to declare it and still not working.